# HTML - Two forms with 'enter' keypress to know which form I am entering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms and I would like to make it easy to type in one form text field and press enter and the page knows what form is being filled out.

Form 1 (example: search):

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="text" name="txt1" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter 1" />
</form>
```

Form 2 (example: login):

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
<input type="text" name="txt2" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter 2" />
</form>
```

Both passes through a PHP script to validate and off to its correct site.
Search is added to a page that is included in every page (MVC) header and the login is on its own page but both come together in one page as two forms.  When logging in on the login page I enter username and password and press enter but it defaults to the search submit button and would like to know its being entered on the login submit button.

Appreciate your help...

Comment: can't just check to see which field has values with `if (!empty($_POST['txt1'])) { // form1 was used } else (!empty($_POST['txt2'])) { // form2 }` ?

Comment: I should have said when I press enter on my keyboard.. I go to logins page and quickly type username and password and hit enter on my keyboard but defaults to the search submit button and does not log me in but attempts to search...

Answer (score 1):

If you give your submit buttons a name, you will be able to detect them in PHP.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter 2" />
```

and later

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Enter 2') // ...
```

Comment: I should have said when I press enter on my keyboard.. I go to logins page and quickly type username and password and hit enter on my keyboard but defaults to the search submit button and does not log me in but attempts to search...

Comment: Is your login form inside your search form?

Comment: Yes because for some reason if I add two forms for the header (search form) and the body form (login form) it doesn't pass through two tokens so I have one form for one token key but different submit buttons.  I would like it to detect which text input type I am using for that specific input text area.  Not sure if thats possible...

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the field names you're looking for in each form, you can key off of that:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['txt1']) {
    // do one thing
} else {
    // do the other
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks everyone! I should have said when I press enter on my keyboard.. I go to logins page and quickly type username and password and hit enter on my keyboard but defaults to the search submit button and does not log me in but attempts to search...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="txt1" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter 1" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="txt2" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter 2" />
</form>
```

The intval() will validate the posted value.

```
if (intval($_POST['form']) == 1){}
elseif (intval($_POST['form']) == 2){}
```

Comment: I should have said when I press enter on my keyboard.. I go to logins page and quickly type username and password and hit enter on my keyboard but defaults to the search submit button and does not log me in but attempts to search...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this article: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml#multiple

Multiple Submit buttons

You can have more than one submit buttons in a form. But, how to identify from the server side which of the buttons was pressed to submit the form?

One way is to have different names for the submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="Insert" value="Insert">
<input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
```

In the server side script you can do a check like this :

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['Update']))
{
  //Do update here..
}
else
if(!empty($_REQUEST['Insert']))
{
  //Do insert Here
}
```

The second method is to have different values for submit buttons with the same name.

```
<input type="submit" name="Operation" value="Insert">
<input type="submit" name="Operation" value="Update">
```

The server side code goes like this (PHP code):

```
if($_REQUEST['Operation'] == 'Update')
{
  //Do update here..
}
else
if($_REQUEST['Operation'] == "Insert")
{
  //Do insert here
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks everyone! I should have said when I press enter on my keyboard.. I go to logins page and quickly type username and password and hit enter on my keyboard but defaults to the search submit button and does not log me in but attempts to search...